# Android disable overlay of ActionBar and NavigationBar for FLAG_TRANSLUCENT

Tags: android, android-actionbar

[image: picture with actionbar and navigationbar overlaying its child]

As you can see by the picture the navigationbar and the statusbar is overlaying the layout. All I have done is

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS); w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    }
```

I have tried to disable the overlay by doing :

```
w.clearFlags(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
        w.clearFlags(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

but with no success. Help  is appreciated with a 1up

Thank you

Comment: ever figure this out? totally annoying

Comment: Unfortunately not. I ended up adding padding to view

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a custom theme that does this? Such a setting `android:windowActionBarOverlay` to true?

If so, disable that in the theme.

Source: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html

Comment: no I am not but thanks anyways. I have tried doing android:windowActionBarOverlay=false in theme but I think the flags added in mainactivity(for transparency) overrides it

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're trying to put your application in Immersive Mode. If so, this is the code I found from Google,which will put your app in immersive mode and on touch will show the Status bar and Navigation Bar.

```
public class ImmersiveActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int INITIAL_HIDE_DELAY = 300;

    private View mDecorView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.immersive_activity);

        final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

        mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        mDecorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(
                new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int flags) {
                        boolean visible = (flags & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) == 0;
                        controlsView.animate()
                                .alpha(visible ? 1 : 0)
                                .translationY(visible ? 0 : controlsView.getHeight());
                    }
                });
        contentView.setClickable(true);
        final GestureDetector clickDetector = new GestureDetector(this,
                new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                        boolean visible = (mDecorView.getSystemUiVisibility()
                                & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) == 0;
                        if (visible) {
                            hideSystemUI();
                        } else {
                            showSystemUI();
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
        contentView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                return clickDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            }
        });

        showSystemUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        // When the window loses focus (e.g. the action overflow is shown),
        // cancel any pending hide action. When the window gains focus,
        // hide the system UI.
        if (hasFocus) {
            delayedHide(INITIAL_HIDE_DELAY);
        } else {
            mHideHandler.removeMessages(0);
        }
    }

    private void hideSystemUI() {
        mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
    }

    private void showSystemUI() {
        mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            hideSystemUI();
        }
    };

    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeMessages(0);
        mHideHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not seem to work. I just need to disable the ovelaying

Comment: When you say disable overlaying, you want the app in full-screen right?

Comment: well not really. notice how the webview moves underneath the actionbar and the navigation bar. Well useres will not be able to click the links that are under the actionbar and nav bar. that is what i want to fix(make it so it does not go underneath)

Comment: This might be of some help http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR

Comment: that does not seem to change anything