# Detect if the Navigation Bar is located right of screen

Tags: android, orientation, windowinsets

I simply need to detect if the system navigation bar is located to the right of the screen as seen in image below.

[image: screenshot with navbar to the right]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect Android Navigation Bar orientation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057035/detect-android-navigation-bar-orientation)

Comment: Please how to change the current orientation location for the navigation bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Insets API and register [`OnApplyWindowInsetsListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) to check the height of the system navigation bar to know the orientation direction:

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(
    window.decorView 
) { _: View, windowInsets: WindowInsetsCompat ->

    val insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())

    if (insets.bottom > 0) {
        // Navigation Bar at Bottom

    } else if (insets.right > 0) {
        // Navigation Bar at Right

    } else if (insets.left > 0) {
        // Navigation Bar at Left

    }

    WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet could help:

```
private boolean isNavigationBarRightOfContent(){
    Rect outRect = new Rect();
    ViewGroup decor = (ViewGroup) mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();
    decor.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(outRect);
    DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return dm.widthPixels == outRect.bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Navigation Bar will only be to the right of the screen if it is in landscape mode. So to detect this, use `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` like this:

```
String orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if(orientation.equals("ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE"){
    // screen in landscape, do what you want to do
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I know this. The thing is that on some devices (most), the NavBar is not to the right but on the bottom.

Comment: @ImmaWake Why do you need to detect this (just wondering)? And as to that... I'm not sure how you would detect it.

Comment: well I posted this question> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058087/android-disable-overlay-of-actionbar-and-navigationbar-for-flag-translucent a couple weeks ago and got no answers that helped. So my work around was adding padding to the top and bottom of my layout matching statusbar and navbar width

Comment: This is no longer always true. If the new gesture navigation is being used, the (very thin) navigation bar ALWAYS appears at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    // retrieve the position of the DecorView
    Rect visibleFrame = new Rect();
    getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(visibleFrame);

    DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    // check if the DecorView takes the whole screen vertically or horizontally
    boolean isRightOfContent = dm.heightPixels == visibleFrame.bottom;
    boolean isBelowContent   = dm.widthPixels  == visibleFrame.right;
```